# Invalid property 'name' of bean class [Country]: Bean property 'name' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Did you mean 'cname'?

Tags: java, spring

I am new to springs, so I was just trying to implement inheritance in spring.

**Customer.java**

```
public class Customer {

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Country.java**

```
public class Country {

    String cname;
    String city;
    public String getCname() {
        return cname;
    }
    public void setCname(String cname) {
        this.cname = cname;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Bean1.xml");
        Customer cus = (Customer) context.getBean("customer");
        System.out.println(cus.getName());
        Country con = (Country) context.getBean("country");
        System.out.println(con.getCname());

    }
}
```

**Bean1.xml**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id = "customer" class = "Customer">
        <property name = "name" value = "Garima"/>    
    </bean>

    <bean id ="country" class="Country" parent="customer">
        <property name = "cname" value = "India"/>
        <property name = "city" value = "Delhi"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Every time I run this without parent in `Bean1.xml`, this is running fine. As soon as I add parent , I receive the below mentioned error. 
Error :  Invalid property `name` of bean class [`Country`]: Bean property `name` is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Did you mean `cname`?
I have noticed this case with many other examples as well.
Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: I tried to remove the class from country bean , but I still received the error.I had to extend the class then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your bean definition suggests that `Customer` **is parent of** `Country` but your class `Country` **doesn't** **extend** `Customer`

```
<bean id ="country" class="Country" parent="customer">
```

So you have two options

1. **Either** remove `parent="customer"` from your bean definition
2. **OR** Extend Customer in Country class like 
   `public class Country extends Customer{...`